# ngx-bootstrap - tabs Angular 4 - Router navigate

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

i have one problem , in my tabs with router, only clicking right on the link works. if you click below or around the link the tab switches but the route does not. and this view the tab is blank, i view that in link the router is ok , but around of tab is a event javascript.

```
<tabset >
    <tab>
        <ng-template tabHeading>
                <a class="routing_link" [routerLink]="['/VariablesParamCrear']" >Asociar</a>
        </ng-template>
    </tab>
    <tab [active]="tabset" >
        <ng-template tabHeading>
            <a class="routing_link" [routerLink]="['/VariablesParamCrear']">Crear</a>
        </ng-template>
        <h1>Hola putitos</h1>
    </tab>
    <tab>
        <ng-template tabHeading>
                <a class="routing_link" [routerLink]="['/VariablesOrder']">Ordenar</a>
        </ng-template>
    </tab>
    <tab>
        <ng-template tabHeading>
                <a class="routing_link" [routerLink]="['/VariablesFilter']">Filtrar</a>
        </ng-template>
    </tab>
```

[image: around of tab]

[image: in link of router]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try putting a method in the component and call it on (click) on the tab itself, like this:

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  Router
} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.less']
})
export class MyComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  goToLink(link: string): void {
    this.router.navigateByUrl(link);
  }
}
```

```html
<tabset>
  <tab (click)="goToLink('/VariablesParamCrear')">
    <ng-template tabHeading>
      Asociar
    </ng-template>
  </tab>
  <tab [active]="tabset" (click)="goToLink('/VariablesParamCrear')">
    <ng-template tabHeading>
      Crear
    </ng-template>
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </tab>
  <tab (click)="goToLink('/VariablesOrder')">
    <ng-template tabHeading>
      Ordenar
    </ng-template>
  </tab>
  <tab (click)="goToLink('/VariablesFilter')">
    <ng-template tabHeading>
      Filtrar
    </ng-template>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

Comment: THANKS!! the (click) event not support the tabs , but i put (select) event , and this fine :D ..